# Apache continues to exist in a chef instance

Tags: apache, nginx, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I'm currently running chef kitchen on vagrant to test my custom recipes for later use in AWS OpsWorks.

For some reason nginx is having problems to start((98: Address already in use)), because of the apache2 service starts running before nginx is started in my recipe. The confusing thing is that I don't have specified apache2 to install. Yet I've tried adding this before my nginx start recipe. But to no avail.
I've tried destroying my vagrant machine multiple times but apache2 still persists.

I'm really confused by this behaviour and would appreciate a lot of if someone might have a clue why this is happening.

*The vagrant machine is running ubuntu 16.04*

**recipes/setup.rb**

```
...
package "apache2" do
    action :purge
end
service "apache2" do
    supports :status => true
    action :stop
    action :disable
    retries 5
end
# enable the server block we just created
    nginx_site 'api' do
    action :enable
    notifies :reload, 'service[nginx]'
end
```

**metadata.rb**

```
...
version '0.1.0'
depends 'apt', '~> 6.0'
depends 'locale', '~> 2.0.0'
depends 'php', '~> 2.2.0'
depends 'chef_nginx', '~> 5.0.7'
depends 'application', '~> 5.1.0'
```

**Berksfile.lock**

```
DEPENDENCIES
  api
    path: .
    metadata: true

GRAPH
  application (5.1.0)
    poise (~> 2.4)
    poise-service (~> 1.0)
  apt (6.0.0)
  build-essential (8.0.0)
    mingw (>= 1.1)
    seven_zip (>= 0.0.0)
  chef_nginx (5.0.7)
    build-essential (>= 0.0.0)
    compat_resource (>= 12.16.3)
    ohai (>= 4.1.0)
    runit (>= 1.6.0)
    yum-epel (>= 0.0.0)
    zypper (>= 0.0.0)
  compat_resource (12.16.3)
  iis (5.0.5)
    windows (>= 1.34.6)
  locale (2.0.0)
  mingw (1.2.5)
    compat_resource (>= 12.16.3)
    seven_zip (>= 0.0.0)
  api (0.1.0)
    application (~> 5.1.0)
    apt (~> 6.0)
    chef_nginx (~> 5.0.7)
    locale (~> 2.0.0)
    php (~> 2.2.0)
  mysql (8.2.0)
  ohai (4.2.3)
    compat_resource (>= 12.14.7)
  packagecloud (0.2.5)
  php (2.2.0)
    build-essential (>= 0.0.0)
    iis (>= 0.0.0)
    mysql (>= 6.0.0)
    xml (>= 0.0.0)
    yum-epel (>= 0.0.0)
  poise (2.7.2)
  poise-service (1.4.2)
    poise (~> 2.0)
  runit (3.0.5)
    packagecloud (>= 0.0.0)
    yum-epel (>= 0.0.0)
  seven_zip (2.0.2)
    windows (>= 1.2.2)
  windows (2.1.1)
    ohai (>= 4.0.0)
  xml (3.1.1)
    build-essential (>= 0.0.0)
  yum-epel (2.1.1)
    compat_resource (>= 12.16.3)
  zypper (0.3.0)
```

Comment: Any log from a run ?

Comment: @Tensibai Here's the output: https://gist.github.com/carlblock/ae00757b86a70ffb2893f09d70601393

Comment: I think you should install nginx before php to avoid bringing down a dependency. It sounds like apt brings down the default http server along with php. But that's just a guess.

Comment: @Tensibai that seemed to do the trick when I added nginx to install before php. I had the same suspicion before and I looked through the dependencies of the php package. apache/httpd is nowhere to be found. However since the dependencies have their own dependencies and so on.. I guess it's hidden somewhere deep there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment thread with @Tensibai he suggested to install nginx before the PHP package. That seems to be the solution to this problem.

[@Tensibai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3627607/tensibai)

> I think you should install nginx before php to avoid bringing down a dependency. It sounds like apt brings down the default http server along with php. But that's just a guess